# antlr3: following token definitions can never be matched

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

For the below grammar:

```
grammar Test;

options {
  language = Java;
  output=AST;
}


reference
 : TASK
 | NAME
 ;

TASK
 : (~'^')+ EOF
 ;

NAME
 : ('A'..'Z')+
 ;
```

I get the following error:

```
error(208): Test.g:19:1: The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: NAME
```

Both the tokens have different charset but still I don't understand why `NAME` is already matched by `TASK`.

I need `TASK` to strictly end with an `EOF` and `NAME` doesn't contain EOF in it. So, both those token can never match the same string.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Your title suggests ANTLR3, but you’ve tagged this with ANTLR3 and ANTLR4.  Assuming you really mean ANTLR3, is there a compelling reason not to use ANTLR4?  ANTLR3 is quite old, and other than supporting an existing grammar, I can’t see much point not using ANTLR4

Comment: You're probing around something that's not well defined. I suggest changing the TASK rule to use a gated semantic predicate to read input.LA(1) until an EOF or non-'A'..'Z' character. `@lexer::members { Boolean foo() { int i = 1; int t = input.LA(i); for (;(int)'A' <= t && t <= (int)'Z'; i++, t = input.LA(i) ) ; return t == -1; } }  TASK : { foo() }? => ('A'..'Z')+ ;`. Yes, you really should use Antlr4.